# Virtual inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I was reading the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) article on virtual inheritance. I followed the whole article but I could not really follow the last paragraph

> This is implemented by providing
>   Mammal and WingedAnimal  with a vtable
>   pointer (or "vpointer") since, e.g.,
>   the memory offset between the
>   beginning of a Mammal and of its
>   Animal  part is unknown until runtime.
>   Thus Bat becomes
>   (vpointer,Mammal,vpointer,WingedAnimal,Bat,Animal).
>   There are two vtable pointers, one per
>   inheritance hierarchy that virtually
>   inherits Animal. In this example, one
>   for Mammal  and one for WingedAnimal.
>   The object size has therefore
>   increased by two pointers, but now
>   there is only one Animal  and no
>   ambiguity. All objects of type Bat
>   will have the same vpointers, but each
>   Bat object will contain its own unique
>   Animal object. If another class
>   inherits from Mammal, such as
>   Squirrel, then the vpointer in the
>   Mammal  object in a Squirrel will be
>   different from the vpointer in the
>   Mammal object in a Bat, although they
>   can still be essentially the same in
>   the special case that the Squirrel 
>   part of the object has the same size
>   as the Bat part, because then the
>   distance from the Mammal to the Animal
>   part is the same. The vtables are not
>   really the same, but all essential
>   information in them (the distance) is.

Can someone please shed some more light on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, you just really need to see some code / diagrams :) Note that there is no mention of this implementation detail in the Standard.

First of all, let's see how to implement methods in C++:

```
struct Base
{
  void foo();
};
```

This is similar to:

```
struct Base {};

void Base_foo(Base& b);
```

And in fact, when you look at a method call within a debugger, you'll often see the `this` argument as the first parameter. It is sometimes called an implicit parameter.

Now, on to the virtual table. In C and C++ it is possible to have pointers to function. A vtable is essentially a table of pointers to functions:

```
struct Base
{
  int a;
};

void Base_set(Base& b, int i) { b.a = i; }
int Base_get(Base const& b) { return b.a; }

struct BaseVTable
{
  typedef void (*setter_t)(Base&, int);
  typedef int (*getter_t)(Base const&);

  setter_t mSetter;
  getter_t mGetter;

  BaseVTable(setter_t s, getter_t g): mSetter(s), mGetter(g) {}
} gBaseVTable(&Base_set, &Base_get);
```

Now I can do something like:

```
void func()
{
  Base b;
  (*gBaseVTable.mSetter)(b, 3);
  std::cout << (*gBaseVTable.mGetter)(b) << std::endl; // print 3
}
```

Now, on to the inheritance. Let's create another structure

```
struct Derived: Base {}; // yeah, Base does not have a virtual destructor... shh

void Derived_set(Derived& d, int i) { d.a = i+1; }

struct DerivedBaseVTable
{
  typedef void (*setter_t)(Derived&,int);
  typedef BaseVTable::getter_t getter_t;

  setter_t mSetter;
  getter_t mGetter;

  DerivedBaseVTable(setter_t s, getter_t g): mSetter(s), mGetter(g) {}
} gDerivedBaseVTable(&Derived_set, &Base_get);
```

And the use:

```
void func()
{
  Derived d;
  (*gDerivedBaseVTable.mSetter)(d, 3);
  std::cout << (*gDerivedBaseVTable.mGetter)(d) << std::endl; // print 4
}
```

But how to automate this ?

- you only need one instance of a vtable per class having at least one virtual function
- each instance of the class will contain a pointer to the vtable as its first attribute (even though you can't really access it by yourself)

Now, what happens in case of multi-inheritance ? Well, inheritance is very much like composition in term of memory layout:

```
|                                     Derived                                   |
|                 BaseA                 |                 BaseB                 |
| vpointer | field1 | field2 | padding? | vpointer | field1 | field2 | padding? |
```

There will thus be 2 virtual tables for `MostDerived`: one to change the methods from `BaseA` and one to change the methods from `BaseB`.

Pure virtual functions are generally represented as a null pointer (simply) in the corresponding field.

And finally, construction and destruction:

Construction

- `BaseA` is constructed: first the vpointer is initialized, then the attributes, then the body of the constructor is executed
- `BaseB` is constructed: vpointer, attributes, body
- `Derived` is constructed: replace the vpointers (both), attributes, body

Destruction

- `Derived is destructed`: body of the destructor, destroy attributes, put the base vpointers back
- `BaseB` is destructed: body, attributes
- `BaseA` is destructed: body, attributes

I think it's pretty comprehensive, I'd be glad if some C++ gurus around there could review this and check I haven't made any stupid mistake. Also, if something is missing, I'd be glad to add it.

Comment: Really comprehensive answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens during virtual inheritance? and how do you explain that Bat becomes (vpointer,Mammal,vpointer,WingedAnimal,Bat,Animal) after virtual inheritance?

Comment: The `Bat` here is an error (that would cause infinite recursion) just ignore it. In case of `virtual` inheritance, the class that is virtually inherited is instanciated only once (by the most derived class) but obviously before the `Mammal` and `WingedAnimal` parts.

Comment: This is one of the coolest explanations I ever read for technical topic.  You truly have the ability to explain complex subjects in simple terms.  I am sure you can be a great teacher !!! BTW, I don't think 'Bat' in wikipedia is an error.  I believe it denotes to the Bat actual fields.  Also, when I read your cool explanation, I felt you forgot to describe where are the Derived fields.  My only question is why the wikipedia article placed 'Bat' in the middle?  Still, I enjoyed reading your explanation!

Answer (score 6):

I cannot, really. This section tries to describe what should be done in a C++ implementation using virtual method tables to provide dynamic binding (in case of multiple inheritance).

If you're not doing a compiler, my advice is: Don't bother. Read your favorite C++ book on inheritance, virtual methods, mulitple inheritance and virtual inheritance.

Plus, usage of a vtable is not required by the C++ standard (IIRC), it's an implementation detail. So really, don't bother.

Comment: I had actually started writing an answer explaining vpointers, but your answer is probably better, unless he wants to read a whole book.

Comment: @Fogh: This thing has been bugging me for a long time...I dont mind reading a whole book

Answer (score 1):

As mkluwe suggested, vpointers are not really a part of the language. However, knowing about
implementation techniques might be useful, especially in a low-level language like C++.

If you really want to learn this, I would recommend [Inside the C++ Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545), which explains this and a lot of other things in detail.