# Multiple class inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, class

Based on the figure below, I wrote my code.
[image]

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class person
{
private:
    int code;
    string name;
public:
    void    setCode(int c) { code=c; }
    int getCode()          { return code; }
    void setName(string s) { name=s; }
    string getName()       { return name; }
};

class account : public person
{
private:
    double pay;
public:
    void    setPay(double p) { pay=p; }
    double getPay()          { return pay; }
};

class admin : public person
{
private:
    string experience;
public:
    void setExper(string e) { experience=e; }
    string getExper()       { return experience; }
};

class master : public account, public admin
{
};

int main()
{
    master mastObj;// create master object.
    mastObj.setName("John");
    system("pause");//to pause console screen, remove it if u r in linux
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler showed these errors:

```
Error   1   error C2385: ambiguous access of 'setName'
Error   2   error C3861: 'setName': identifier not found    
Error   3   IntelliSense: "master::setName" is ambiguous
```

Comment: First of all, your question title is not an actual question, regardless of the question mark at the end of the sentence. Secondly, it is better to actually describe a problem, explain what you have tried so far, instead of just pasting a piece of code and have others fix it for you.

Comment: Your code formatting was a bit of a mess. Code is for humans too :) Especially since you want _us_ to read it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual Inheritance Confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148470/virtual-inheritance-confusion)

Comment: @sehe: I think it's safe to say that code is *predominantly* for humans :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need virtual inheritance:

```
class account: public virtual person{
....
}

class admin: public virtual  person{
...
}
```

**PS** And your pay, code fields lack initialization! This could lead to embarassing errors (like paying the cleaner several million of dollars :)):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class person
{
   // ...
   person() : code(0), name("anonymous") {}

};

class account : public virtual person
{
    // ...
    account() : pay(0) {}
};

class admin : public virtual person
{
    // ...
    admin() : experience("unknown") {}
};
```

Answer (score 7):

It is classic example of [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) in C++ when you use multiple inheritance.

The solution is : [Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

That is, you should do this:

```
class account : public virtual person 
{                   //^^^^^^^note this
   //code
};

class admin : public virtual  person
{                  //^^^^^^^note this
   //code
};
```

I just found really good posts on this site, so I would redirect you to those answers here:

- [Virtual inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175437/virtual-inheritance-in-c)
- [Virtual Inheritance Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148470/virtual-inheritance-confusion)
- [Virtual inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179854/virtual-inheritance-in-c)
- [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-virtual-base-class)

which also means, this topic should be voted for close.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `mastObj.master::admin::person::setName("John");`